# Why does this try statement use the catch statement?

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class bank {
    public static void login() {
        double balance;
        try {
            boolean subtract;
            boolean amounttaken;
            // This is to see if you want to withdraw money
            System.out.println("Do you want to withdraw money?");
            Scanner SCaddOrWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
            subtract = SCaddOrWithdraw.nextBoolean();
            if (subtract) {
                System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                Scanner SCamounttaken = new Scanner(System.in);
                amounttaken = SCamounttaken.nextBoolean();
                System.out.println("Subtract");
            } else if (!subtract) {
                System.out.print("Ask for bal");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a **try** statement and in the first part of the **if** I tell it to print subtract but instead it calls the **catch** statement. Can someone please help?
Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in coding.

Comment: Please provide what values you're using as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a complete structure.

```
try {
    // Statement Which May Throw Exceptions
} catch(Exception e) {
    // If any statement throws the exception
    // Do alternative flow here
}
```

If your code within the try block may throw exception, you can do the alternate of it. Like in your above code, if anyone input a string instead of boolean it will throw InputMismatchException, which will be captured in catch block and you can print the error message to user nice and neatly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `subtract` and `amounttaken` as `boolean` variables and therefore they can take only `true` or `false` as the values e.g. given below is a sample run:

```
Do you want to withdraw money?
true
How much would you like to withdraw?
true
Subtract
```

If you try to enter a value different from `true` or `false`, you will get `InputMismatchException`.

I think you want to enter some decimal number (amount) for the variable, `amounttaken`. If yes, declare it as `double` or `float` instead of `boolean` e.g.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        login();
    }

    public static void login() {
        double balance;
        try {
            boolean subtract;
            double amounttaken;// Changed to double
            // This is to see if you want to withdraw money
            System.out.println("Do you want to withdraw money?");
            Scanner SCaddOrWithdraw = new Scanner(System.in);
            subtract = SCaddOrWithdraw.nextBoolean();
            if (subtract) {
                System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                Scanner SCamounttaken = new Scanner(System.in);
                amounttaken = SCamounttaken.nextDouble();// Changed for double
                System.out.println("Subtract");
            } else if (!subtract) {
                System.out.print("Ask for bal");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Do you want to withdraw money?
true
How much would you like to withdraw?
3000
Subtract
```